# What does "method process in class ForeachWriter of type (value: org.apache.spark.sql.Row)Unit is not defined" mean with ForeachWriter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use the foreach sink while writing my dataframe to a hive table:

```
// dp is my dataframe (aggregated streaming data)
dp.writeStream.foreach(
  new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = true
    def process(record: String): Unit = {
      //dp.createOrReplaceTempView("tableA")
      // i need to do insert into tablename (select * from tableA)
    }
    def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
  }
).start()
```

I am getting following error

> error: object creation impossible, since method process in class ForeachWriter of type (value: org.apache.spark.sql.Row)Unit is not defined

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more careful with the types, i.e. compare the type in `ForeachWriter[Row]` and `def process(record: String): Unit`. They are incompatible and hence the error.

From the scaladoc of [org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter):

> `abstract class ForeachWriter[T]`

and

> `abstract def process(value: T): Unit`

The `T` type is the key here. Use `def process(record: Row): Unit` and that should fix the compilation error.

Comment: can you please help on this question ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379179/how-to-insert-data-to-hive-using-foreach-method-in-spark-structured-streaming