# how to insert data to HIVE using foreach method in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I try inserting data to HIVE table using foreach method.

I use spark 2.3.0.

Here is my code

```
   df_drop_window.writeStream
     .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row]() {
       override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true
       override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
         println(s">> Processing ${value}")
         // how to onvert the value as dataframe ?
       }
       override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
       }
     }).outputMode("update").start()
```

As you can see above, I want convert the "value" to dataframe and insert data to HIVE table like insert into tablename(select * from dataframe). can someone help how to do it ?am new to spark streaming

I can see only following option available. can some say how can i convert value:Row  to data[image]frame ?

I have tried following but am getting error (org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable)

```
            df.writeStream
       .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row]() {
       override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true
       override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
       val rowsRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(value))
       val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRdd, schema)
       df2.createOrReplaceTempView("testing2")
       spark.sql("insert into table are.table_name1 Partition(date) select * from testing2")
       }
       override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
       }
       }).outputMode("append").start()
```

Comment: why are you not using `format("hive")` instead? or you write as parquet and use the path to the Hive database?

Comment: Not convinced the right approach here

Comment: Can you provide the right approach

Comment: @AKSW .. How can i covert the value:row to dataframe

Comment: that is the wrong way...what do you ant to do with a single `Row`? that doesn't make any sense. Please search for `spark stream write to hive` - there are plenty explanations how to do it properly, even some Github projects. But using a single `Row`, convert it to a dataframe and then write to Hive is obviously the wrong way. This can't scale, isn't this obvious?! I told you one way with writing parquet to a hive table directory. I give you one pointer to a Github project> https://github.com/jerryshao/spark-hive-streaming-sink - the rest is up to you, google returns many hits

Comment: OK.. then what is the use of foreach ?

Comment: can some one explain how to perform inserting data HIVE (spark 2.3.0)

Comment: @ AKSW since am using spark structured streaming, i cant use format("hive"). so can you please tell me how can i convert my value to dataframe? i have updated my question with available options showing in spark console.. please help

Answer (score 0):

Spark Session is not serializable on the executor side, you need to broadcast spark session